# Are Parts of Speech / Syntactic Grammar most on topic here? (vs on other SE sites)

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

I don't normally come on ELL,
I'm a native English speaker, but I don't think I have much real capacity to answers the questions of others on it.

Recently in my post-grad research in computational linguistics, I've found that my (primary/secondary) education has been lacking in covering parts of speech and various other syntactic questions I now find myself having.

So I am attempting rectify that though reading books etc, but when I get stuck I come (as always :-D ) to stack exchange.

My latest two questions it has been suggested would be a better fit here:

- ELU: [For non-modal/auxiliary verb, is the non-3rd person singular present form always the same as the base form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261504/for-non-modal-auxiliary-verb-is-the-non-3rd-person-singular-present-form-always)
- Lingistics: [If two verbs are in a row, is the first always an Auxiliary?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12820/if-two-verbs-are-in-a-row-is-the-first-always-an-auxiliary)

I now understand why the linguistics one was closed. So I am wondering if those would have been more on-topic here, or on English Language Usage.

I always overlook the site, thinking it is just for people learning English as a second(/third/...) language, but perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: I think you're more or less correct. However, parts of speech are important for many learners because without having some ideas about the PoS of English, it's almost impossible for learners to understand complicated sentences. Then again, the PoS that learners need to know, IMHO, don't have to be a very precise set, just enough to enable the learners to see sentence structures would be fine. However, in part-of-speech tagging tasks (computational linguistics), you may need to be more precise, and may need to force yourself to deal with ambiguous cases (e.g. what is *here* in *They're here*.)

Answer (score 3):

I've been active on both sites for some time, and I'm completely at a loss why a regular at ELU would have steered you toward ELL for your first question.

As a matter of fact, ELU seems to get precious few questions nowadays aimed at its purported target audience, and I think yours is one of the few questions that does.

Anyhow, I'd put more stock your question's four upvotes than in the comment by Mr. Ashworth. Had you asked that question here on ELL, I probably would have thought it belonged on ELU.